# Trying to create a key in registry database

Tags: vbscript

I have done this code, but it seems that it dosen't work. I don't why. I have searched on google, but no luck. :(

```
Set objREG = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim lstrKeyPath, lstrValueName, lstrValue
lstrKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Canon\GARO1\"
lstrValueName = "LocaleInfo"
objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,lstrKeyPath,lstrValueName,lstrValue
msgbox lstrValue  <--- This works.
if IsNull(lstrValue) then 
  lstrKeyPath = lstrKeyPath & lstrValueName
else
  lstrValueName = "LocaleTest" 
  lstrKeyPath = "Software\Test\"
  Return = objReg.CreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,lstrKeyPath)
  if Return = 0 Then
    msgbox "Yes"
  else 
    msgbox "No"
  end if
end if
Set OBJREG = Nothing
```

I can't see my "Test" key in the registry

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following to check for and insert registry keys if they don't exist:

```
Dim WshShell, Test, blExists, DQ
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DQ = chr(34)

RegKeyPath = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LFS\"
RegValueName = "URL:LFS Protocol"
Test = RegKeyExists(RegKeyPath,RegValueName)

If Test = False Then
    WshShell.RegWrite RegKeyPath, "URL:LFS Protocol" ,"REG_SZ"
End If

'Function Returns False if the regkey isnt found otherwise it returns 
'The registry key value specified
Function RegKeyExists(sRegKey,sRegValueName)

    On Error Resume Next    

    Dim WSHShellRegTest, Test, blExists
    Set WSHShellRegTest = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    blTrueFalse = True

    Test = WSHShellRegTest.RegRead (sregkey + sRegValueName)

    If Err Then
        RegKeyExists = False
        Err.clear
        Exit Function
    End if

    Set WSHShellRegTest = Nothing

    RegKeyExists = Test

End Function
```